# (react.js) why losing value of the fields and why is re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

what would be the reason I lose the value on the inputs when I try to add another one,?

in the component I set the useState with an array of an empty string, and when I click the add button it ads another slot in the array, but every time I add a field, the value in the rest of the form is reset and lost. I believe the app is re-rendering.

```
const IngridientsInputField = () => {

     function newIngridient(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        setStateIngridients([...stateIngridients, ''] )
        setStateCounter(stateCounter +1)
    }

    return (
        <div className="ingridients">
            <h3>number of ingridients {stateCounter}</h3>
            { stateIngridients.map(() => (
                    <input type="text" name="ingridient" title="ingridient" placeholder={`ingridient (example: pineapple)`} />
                )) 
            }
            <button onClick={newIngridient}>add + </button>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: where is your `useState()` hook?

Comment: in the parent component 
this is how the component begins

const RecipeForm = (props) => {    
    const [stateIngridients, setStateIngridients] = useState(['']);
    const IngridientsInputField = () => {

Comment: You want to add ingredients to an array? Why do you want a new input field each time an ingredient is added?